# Regressions to check function override issue

Tags: c++, polymorphism, regression

Compiler: GCC

In below code, all 3 Foo()'s signature were `Foo(bool b)`, but someone updated the code and forgot to change `DeriveB::Foo`. This passes compilation. How can we prevent this kind of mistakes?

```
class Base {
  virtual Foo(bool b, int i);
}

class DerivedA : public Base {
  Foo(bool b, int i);
}

class DerivedB : public Base {
  Foo(bool b);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C++11, you can use the `override` specifier, which I believe is also supported as an extension by MSVC for C++03 code.

If you're using g++ or clang, passing `-Woverloaded-virtual` to the compiler is what you're after I think. For your example above, g++ reports:

```
so_virt.cc:2:16: warning: ‘virtual void Base::Foo(bool, int)’ was hidden [-Woverloaded-virtual]
   virtual void Foo(bool b, int i);
            ^
so_virt.cc:10:8: warning:   by ‘void DerivedB::Foo(bool)’ [-Woverloaded-virtual]
   void Foo(bool b);
```

Comment: -Woverloaded-virtual is a good one. Though it would reports some false positive (the one intended to be declared in different function signature).

Comment: True, but (in my experience at least) even if a derived class is intending to provide an overload with a different signature, hiding the base class method (by forgetting the `using` declaration) is usually not desired.

Answer (score 1):

The `override` specifier might be what you want. If you use it in the declaration of `Foo` in the derived classes you'd get an error for `DerivedB::Foo` since it got a different signature.

```
class Base {
  virtual Foo(bool b, int i);
}

class DerivedA : public Base {
  Foo(bool b, int i) override; // would be fine
}

class DerivedB : public Base {
  Foo(bool b) override; // gives an error
}
```

It gives an error if the function in the derived class got a different signature of the one in the base class or if the one in the base class isn't declared `virtual`.

There's no way to force people to use the override specifier in derived classes tho so you still got to remember to use it. But it might at least catch errors when changing the function signature. For more info on override look [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/override).

Comment: What if we compile in C++03, and the override keyword is not supported?

Comment: @Stan I don't know about any way to get something similar there.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Base {
 virtual Foo(bool b, int i) = 0;
}

class DerivedA : public Base {
 Foo(bool b, int i);
}

class DerivedB : public Base {
 Foo(bool b);
}
```

Notice how I appended `=0` to `virtual Foo(bool b, int i) = 0`

Comment: The Base::Foo is not a pure virtual function, we have definition for it.